# An unexpected behavior in my three-phase circuit simulation that I can't understand

Tags: three-phase

For a working report on my university, I simply have the goal of testing the two-wattmeter method on a three-phase circuit with delta load which schematic can be seen below:
[image]

It should be a very simple experience, but something really strange is happening. The current on load between phase A and C has two times more currents than in other loads.
I perform measures in RMS voltage in each load to understand why and to get more confused, with the same terms current, the load AC has two more currents than the other ones. All loads have the same characteristics and the same value, it doesn't make sense, does someone know how to explain it and fix it??

if you want to see my MATLAB Simulink to a better understanding, you can download it at this link:

[my three-phase circuit schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SYSNXUyygVvs7O_urhLPAQZ9obP5Qhkx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Image is too small to see the numbers, and I don't have Matlab so...

Comment: @BruceAbbott I ask you apologizes for the too-small image size. I fixed it, maybe now you can see the numbers, I checked and I could see the numbers with no problems

Comment: _" I perform measures in RMS voltage in each load"_ - the meter labeled Vac (blue box) is actually connected between B and C. Is the voltage between A and C the same? You have two current meters between A and C (Iac and Iac1). Why? The load impedances are not stated. Please verify the value of each one.